# Using seperate threads to execute a sequence of timed events using Queue.Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, queue, robotics

I am working on a Seniour Design project automating a power wheelchair allowing for different control methods like speech recognition. With the help of the  of the wheelchair controller manufacturer a system was configured with python as the programming interface. With help from a software engineer the code below was structured to control the wheelchair direction and speed. The program uses `threading.thread` to pass `dt.control` events into a `queue.queue` to be executed until a new `dt.control` event is issued. I've been able to put together a speech recognition program that uses the login and control functions as a way into the thread to control the wheelchair. I now would like to issue a series of timed `dt.control` events using a timer to pass in the sequence of `dt.control` events to be executed by the queue one event at a time. I am fairly new to python an am having trouble coming up with a way to do this.

```
import serial
import time
import datetime
import Queue
import threading

class DriveThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ser):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.ser = ser
        self.incValue = 0

    def run(self):
        direction = None
        speed = None
        prof = 0
        while 1:
            try:
                control = self.queue.get(timeout = 0.5)
                speed = control[0]
                direction = control[1]
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

#  PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
#
#  interface into this thread.
#
    def login(self):
        checksum = 0xc1
        #stuff
        self.queue.put([0,0])

    def control(self, direction, speed):
        self.queue.put([self.sign(direction), self.sign(speed)])

    def give_joystick_control(self):
        #stuff
        ser.write(string)

#  PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
#
### These functions are private to the thread.
#        
    def drive(self, speed, direction, prof):
        inc = int(self.inc_value())
        #stuff

    def inc_value(self):
        if(self.incValue<255):
            self.incValue = self.incValue+1
        else:
            self.incValue = 0
        return self.incValue

    def send_string(self, string):
        self.ser.write(string)

    def read(self):
        #stuff 

    def sign(self, val):
        #stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 'COM6'

    ser = serial.Serial(port, 115200, timeout = 0)

    time.sleep(0.1)

    dt = DriveThread(ser)
    dt.start()

    while 1:
        cmd = raw_input("Enter command: l=logon, n=neutral (default), f=forward, r=reverse, lr=looping right, ll=looping left, c=clockwise, cc=counterclockwise, and j=joystick: ")

        if cmd == 'l':
            dt.login()

        if cmd == 'n':
            dt.control(0, 0)
        if cmd == 'f': 
            dt.control(0, 50)
        if cmd == 'r':
            dt.control(0, -50)
        if cmd == 'lr':
            dt.control(50, 50)
        if cmd == 'll':
            dt.control(-50, 50)   
        if cmd == 'c':
            dt.control(50, 0)
        if cmd == 'cc':
            dt.control(-50, 0)
        if cmd == 'j':
            dt.give_joystick_control()
```

This following bit of code is based on an open source speech recognition project called Pocketsphinx and its implementation in a python library called speakpython. This code imports the code above as a module and speech recognition passes the functions below to dt.control callables. Both codes are working fine, what would a new implementation look like that assigns priority to a series of dt.control events so that they are executed in a sequence. I have been told that setting up seperate threads can possibly accomplish this but this is new territory for me and not sure how to go about that.

```
from bt_2 import DriveThread
import serial
import time
import sys;
import os;
from SpeakPython.SpeakPythonRecognizer import SpeakPythonRecognizer

ser = serial.Serial(port, 115200, timeout = 0)

time.sleep(.1)

dt = DriveThread(ser)
dt.start()
stop=False;

def quit():
    stop = True;
    print "quit";
    sys.exit(0);

def login():
        global cmd
        cmd='l';

def neutral():
        global cmd
        cmd='n';

def forward():
        global cmd
        cmd='f';

def reverse():
        global cmd
        cmd='r';

def right():
        global cmd
        cmd='lr';

def left():
        global cmd
        cmd='ll';

def clockwise():
        global cmd
        cmd='c';

def cclockwise():
        global cmd
        cmd='cc';

def manual():
        global cmd
        cmd = raw_input("Enter command: l=logon, n=neutral (default), f=forward, r=reverse, lr=looping right, ll=looping left, c=clockwise, cc=counterclockwise, and j=joystick: ")

def execute(out_str):
    print out_str;
    if not out_str == None:
        exec out_str;
    else:
        print "Couldn't recognize.";

print "Ready.";

recog = SpeakPythonRecognizer(execute, "chairCommands");

recog.setDebug(1);

try:
        while not stop:

        recog.recognize();
        dt.login()
        print cmd
        if cmd == 'l':
           dt.login()

        if cmd == 'n':
            dt.control(0, 0)
        if cmd == 'f':
            dt.control(0, 50)
        if cmd == 'r':
            dt.control(0, -50)
        if cmd == 'lr':
            dt.control(50, 50)
        if cmd == 'll':
            dt.control(-50, 50)   
        if cmd == 'c':
            dt.control(40, 0)
        if cmd == 'cc':
            dt.control(-40, 0)
        if cmd == 'j':
            dt.give_joystick_control()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stop = True;
    print "Interrupted.";
finally:
    print("program Terminated")
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do and what does it actually do? Also, you could probably remove a lot of the code (like reading and parsing of serial data) to better demonstrate the problem you're having (which I assume from your question has to do with queues and threading).

Comment: A good chunk of the code is dedicated to proper execution of the thread. The public functions are what are callable in the while loop. dt.login() logs in a third party device (pc), dt.control executes dc motor control, dt.give_joystick_control returns manual control of the wheelchair. When logged in to the system raw_input is prompted (cmd== ' ') from third party and output is generated with a wheelchair response. There is more code that imports this code as a module and interfaces with a program that runs speech recognition.

Comment: At this points single speech commands execute a single dt.control callable. For example, a forward command passes dt.control(0,50) and the chair goes forward until a new command (dt.control) is issued. The goal is to have a single speech command execute a series of dt.control callables to have the wheelchair follow a preset path.

Comment: Is there anything in particular you don't like about your current implementation?

Comment: The code you have basically does the job. Depending on your requirements, it might already be a good option. For example, it has the following property: it does not start interpreting a new command until the last one has finished executing. So if a command takes a long time to execute, all other queued commands will have to wait. On the other hand, you ensure that commands will get executed in order they were issued. You could have a different implementation, for example, where you execute each command in a new thread. This way commands would not block one another, but might lose order.

Comment: There was actually a very simple solution utilizing a function to layout the sequence of dt.control callables with timer.sleep() delays. No seperate thread necessary.